# How to get an option's name in a Rundeck JOB?

Tags: rundeck

I have a JOB rundeck called "TEST"

I have an option called country

this option retreives a list of key, value from a remote URL as :

```
[
  {"name":"FRANCE", "value":"FR"},
  {"name":"ITALY", "value":"IT"},
  {"name":"ALGERIA", "value":"DZ"}
]
```

I would like to use both of the name and the value in a job step.

```
echo ${option.country.name} 
echo ${option.country.value}
```

But this doesn't work and I'm not able to get the name of the parameter

getting the value can be done using `${option.country}`

Is there any trick to get the parameter **name** ???

Comment: afaik, there is no way you can get the option.[name].name by rundeck's function. you may wish to call a cgi script with value as argument and the script return the 'name' field of the json

Comment: Can someone please tell if this provision has been added yet or not. Is there a way to access an options name?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record answer: Maybe the best approach is to create some script-step that reads the JSON file and extracts the name, also, you can use the same value name like [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5898#issuecomment-611817976) example (of course is not applicable for all cases).